# How to convert string into protoreflect.ProtoMessage or into anypb

Tags: go

I'm trying to use server sent event `eventsoource` through gRPC gateway, so read [this](https://dev.to/techschoolguru/go-generate-serialize-protobuf-message-4m7a)
and [this](https://hackmd.io/@prysmaticlabs/eventstream-api) and came out with the below `proto`

```
syntax = "proto3";

package protobuf;
option go_package = "/proto";

import "google/protobuf/any.proto";
import "google/protobuf/empty.proto";
import "google/api/annotations.proto";

service Events {
  rpc StreamEvents (google.protobuf.Empty) returns (stream EventSource) {
    option (google.api.http) = {
      get: "/v1/rawdata/stream"
    };
  }
}

message Empty{}

message EventSource {
  string event = 1;
  google.protobuf.Any data = 2;
}
```

And generated all required gRPC files (Message/Service/Gateway) using:

```bash
protoc -I ./proto \
  --go_out ./proto --go_opt paths=source_relative \
  --go-grpc_out ./proto --go-grpc_opt paths=source_relative \
  --grpc-gateway_out ./proto --grpc-gateway_opt paths=source_relative \
  ./proto/data.proto
```

And trying to registered the generated service and gateway at my main app, as:

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "sync"
    "syscall"

    "github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/v2/runtime"
    _ "github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3"
    "google.golang.org/grpc"
    "google.golang.org/grpc/credentials/insecure"

    pb "walistner/proto"
)

func main() {
    gRPcPort := ":50005"
    // Create a gRPC listener on TCP port
    lis, err := net.Listen("tcp", gRPcPort)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to listen: %v", err)
    }

    // Create a gRPC server object
    s := grpc.NewServer()

    // Attach the Greeter service to the server
    pb.RegisterEventsServer(s, server{})

    log.Println("Serving gRPC server on 0.0.0.0:50005")

    // Serve gRPC server
    grpcTerminated := make(chan struct{})
    go func() {
        if err := s.Serve(lis); err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("failed to serve: %v", err)
            close(grpcTerminated) // In case server is terminated without us requesting this
        }
    }()

    // Create a client connection to the gRPC server we just started
    // This is where the gRPC-Gateway proxies the requests
    //  gateWayTarget := fmt.Sprintf("0.0.0.0%s", gRPcPort)
    conn, err := grpc.DialContext(
        context.Background(),
        gRPcPort,
        grpc.WithBlock(),
        grpc.WithTransportCredentials(insecure.NewCredentials()),
    )
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("Failed to dial server:", err)
    }

    gwmux := runtime.NewServeMux()

    // This handle to use JSON ServerSentEvent, not the gRPC one
    //http.HandleFunc("/sse", passer.HandleSignal)
    // Register custom route for  GET /hello/{name}
    //err = gwmux.HandlePath("GET", "/sse", passer.HandleSignal)
    //if err != nil {
    //  fmt.Println("Error:", err)
    //}

    // This handler just to confirm server is up and running
    // Register custom route for  GET /hello/{name}
    err = gwmux.HandlePath("GET", "/hello/{name}", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, pathParams map[string]string) {
        w.Write([]byte("hello " + pathParams["name"]))
    })
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error:", err)
    }

    // Register the gRPC ServerSentEvent
    err = pb.RegisterEventsHandler(context.Background(), gwmux, conn)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("Failed to register gateway:", err)
    }

    gwServer := &http.Server{
        Addr:    ":8090",
        Handler: allowCORS(gwmux),
    }

    log.Println("Serving gRPC-Gateway on http://localhost:8090")

    fmt.Println("run POST request of: http://localhost:8090/v1/rawdata/stream")
    fmt.Println("or run curl -X GET -k http://localhost:8090/v1/rawdata/stream")
    log.Fatal(gwServer.ListenAndServe()) // <- This line alone could be enough ang no need for all the lines after,

    // the application is probably doing other things and you will want to be
    // able to shutdown cleanly; passing in a context is a good method..
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
    defer cancel() // Ensure cancel function is called eventually

    grpcWebTerminated := make(chan struct{})
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        if err := gwServer.ListenAndServe(); err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Web server (GRPC) shutdown: %s", err)
        }
        close(grpcWebTerminated) // In case server is terminated without us requesting this
    }()

    // Wait for the web server to shutdown OR the context to be cancelled...
    select {
    case <-ctx.Done():
        // Shutdown the servers (there are shutdown commands to request this)
    case <-grpcTerminated:
        // You may want to exit if this happens (will be due to unexpected error)
    case <-grpcWebTerminated:
        // You may want to exit if this happens (will be due to unexpected error)
    }
    // Wait for the goRoutines to complete
    <-grpcTerminated
    <-grpcWebTerminated

    // Listen to Ctrl+C (you can also do something else that prevents the program from exiting)
    c := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(c, os.Interrupt, syscall.SIGTERM)

    <-c
    if client.IsConnected() {
        passer.data <- sseData{
            event:   "notification",
            message: "Server is shut down at the host machine...",
        }
        client.Disconnect()
    }
}

// allowCORS allows Cross Origin Resoruce Sharing from any origin.
// Don't do this without consideration in production systems.
func allowCORS(h http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        if origin := r.Header.Get("Origin"); origin != "" {
            w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin)
        }
        h.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}
```

And the main part that is having an issue, is ther `gateway` registration:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "sync"
    pb "walistner/proto"

    "google.golang.org/grpc/metadata"
    "google.golang.org/grpc/peer"
    "google.golang.org/protobuf/reflect/protoreflect"
    "google.golang.org/protobuf/types/known/anypb"
    "google.golang.org/protobuf/types/known/emptypb"
)

type server struct {
    pb.UnimplementedEventsServer
}

func (s server) StreamEvents(_ *emptypb.Empty, srv pb.Events_StreamEventsServer) error {
    if p, ok := peer.FromContext(srv.Context()); ok {
        fmt.Println("Client ip is:", p.Addr.String())
    }
    md := metadata.New(map[string]string{"Content-Type": "text/event-stream", "Connection": "keep-alive"})

    srv.SetHeader(md)

    //use wait group to allow process to be concurrent
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    for {
        incomingInput := <-passer.data
        wg.Add(1)
        //go func(count int64) {
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
      
            myData := incomingInput.data <---------------This is a string

            // Convert data to *anypb.Any
            data, err := anypb.New(myData.(protoreflect.ProtoMessage)) <----- tried this but it failed
            if err != nil {
                //...
            }

            resp := pb.EventSource{
                Event: incomingInput.event,
                Data:  data, // <---------- this is required to be of type *anypb.Any
            }

            if err := srv.Send(&resp); err != nil {
                log.Printf("send error %v", err)
            }
        }()
    }

    wg.Wait()
    return nil
}
```

My data structure inside the go app is:

```golang
type sseData struct {
    event, message string
}
type DataPasser struct {
    data       chan sseData
    logs       chan string
    connection chan struct{} // To control maximum allowed clients connections
}

var passer *DataPasser

func init() {
    passer = &DataPasser{
        data:       make(chan sseData),
        logs:       make(chan string),
        connection: make(chan struct{}, maxClients),
    }
}
```

Comment: `(myData.(protoreflect.ProtoMessage))` - you said `myData` was a `string`, so this should panic.  What does `myData` look like?  Is it a proto serialized to a string?  If so you need to do `proto.UnmarshalText(myData, myProto)` where `myProto := &somepb.MyDataTypeAsProto{}`.